# Simple Breakout/Arkanoid clone with SFML

Tags: c++, beginner, game, c++11, sfml

I'm doing this small *Breakout* clone for school, and I've looked at heaps of people's takes on Breakout and tried to combine bits and pieces that I liked. Only problem that I'm having is getting the game to end when the ball hits the bottom window edge and sounds.

You should be able to copy/paste the code into a project, only issues being with the sound and text.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
int x = 5;
constexpr int windowWidth ( 800 ), windowHeight( 600 );
constexpr float ballRadius( 10.f ), ballVelocity( 6.f );
constexpr float paddleWidth( 100.f ), paddleHeight( 20.f ), paddleVelocity( 8.f );
constexpr float blockWidth( 60.f ), blockHeight( 20.f );
constexpr int countBlocksX( 11 ), countBlocksY( 6 );
constexpr int countBlocks2X(11), countBlocks2Y(3);
bool isPlaying = true;


struct Ball
{
    CircleShape shape;
    Vector2f velocity{ -ballVelocity, -ballVelocity };

    Ball(float mX, float mY)
    {
        shape.setPosition(mX, mY);
        shape.setRadius(ballRadius);
        shape.setFillColor(Color::Yellow);
        shape.setOrigin(ballRadius, ballRadius);
    }

    void update()
    {
        //Need to make the ball bounce of the window edges
        shape.move(velocity);
        //If it's leaving on the left edge, we set a positive horizontal value.
        if (left() < 0)
            velocity.x = ballVelocity;
        //Same for the right
        else if (right() > windowWidth)
            velocity.x = -ballVelocity;
        //Top
        if (top() < 0)
            velocity.y = ballVelocity;
        //And bottom
        else if (bottom() > windowHeight)
            velocity.y = -ballVelocity;

    }

    float x() { return shape.getPosition().x; }
    float y() { return shape.getPosition().y; }
    float left() { return x() - shape.getRadius(); }
    float right() { return x() + shape.getRadius(); }
    float top() { return y() - shape.getRadius(); }
    float bottom() { return y() + shape.getRadius(); }
};

//Create the Rectangle shape class for the brick
struct Rectangle
{
    RectangleShape shape;
    float x()       { return shape.getPosition().x; }
    float y()       { return shape.getPosition().y; }
    float left()    { return x() - shape.getSize().x / 2.f; }
    float right()   { return x() + shape.getSize().x / 2.f; }
    float top()     { return y() - shape.getSize().y / 2.f; }
    float bottom()  { return y() + shape.getSize().y / 2.f; }
};

//Class for the paddle
struct Paddle : public Rectangle
{
    //Create a variable for speed.
    Vector2f velocity;
    //Set the variables for the paddle rectangle shape.
    Paddle(float mX, float mY)
    {
        shape.setPosition(mX, mY);
        shape.setSize({ paddleWidth, paddleHeight });
        shape.setFillColor(Color::Red);
        shape.setOrigin(paddleWidth / 2.f, paddleHeight / 2.f);
    }
    // Within the update function we check if the player is moving the paddle
    void update()
    {
        shape.move(velocity);
        //To ensure that the paddle stays inside the window we only change the Velocity when it's inside the boundaries
        //Making it impossible to move outside when the initial velocity is set to zero
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::Left) && left() > 0)
        velocity.x = -paddleVelocity;

        else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::Right) && right() < windowWidth)
            velocity.x = paddleVelocity;
        //If the player isn't pressing a buttom (legt/right) the velocity is set to zero.
        else
            velocity.x = 0;
    }
};
//Another class for the bricks
struct Brick : public Rectangle
{
    bool destroyed{ false };

    Brick(float mX, float mY)
    {
        shape.setPosition(mX, mY);
        shape.setSize({ blockWidth, blockHeight });
        shape.setFillColor(Color::Black);
        shape.setOrigin(blockWidth / 2.f, blockHeight / 2.f);
    }
};

//C++ Feature template allows us to create a generic funtion to check if two shapes are intersecting or colliding.
template <class T1, class T2>
bool isIntersecting(T1& mA, T2& mB)
{
    return mA.right() >= mB.left() && mA.left() <= mB.right() &&
        mA.bottom() >= mB.top() && mA.top() <= mB.bottom();
}

void collisionTest(Paddle& mPaddle, Ball& mBall)
{
    if (!isIntersecting(mPaddle, mBall)) return;

    mBall.velocity.y = -ballVelocity;
    if (mBall.x() < mPaddle.x())
        mBall.velocity.x = -ballVelocity;
    else
        mBall.velocity.x = ballVelocity;
}


void collisionTest(Brick& mBrick, Ball& mBall)
{
    if (!isIntersecting(mBrick, mBall)) return;
    mBrick.destroyed = true;

    float overlapLeft{ mBall.right() - mBrick.left() };
    float overlapRight{ mBrick.right() - mBall.left() };
    float overlapTop{ mBall.bottom() - mBrick.top() };
    float overlapBottom{ mBrick.bottom() - mBall.top() };

    bool ballFromLeft(abs(overlapLeft) < abs(overlapRight));
    bool ballFromTop(abs(overlapTop) < abs(overlapBottom));

    float minOverlapX{ ballFromLeft ? overlapLeft : overlapRight };
    float minOverlapY{ ballFromTop ? overlapTop : overlapBottom };

    if (abs(minOverlapX) < abs(minOverlapY))
        mBall.velocity.x = ballFromLeft ? -ballVelocity : ballVelocity;
    else
        mBall.velocity.y = ballFromTop ? -ballVelocity : ballVelocity;
}
int main()
{

    //We render/create the window
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight ), "Breakout Game" );
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    Paddle paddle{ windowWidth / 2, windowHeight - 50 };
    int x = 5;
//Here we use an unconditiional goto statement to allow the user to restart the game.   
restart:
    //We reference the Ball, Paddle and Bricks
    Ball ball{ windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2 };
    vector<Brick> bricks;
    //vector<Brick2> bricks2;

    for (int iX{ 0 }; iX < countBlocksX; ++iX)
        for (int iY{ 0 }; iY < countBlocksY; ++iY)
            bricks.emplace_back(
                (iX + 1) * (blockWidth + 3) + 22, (iY + 2) * (blockHeight + 3));


    // Load the text font
    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Initialize the pause message
    sf::Text loseGame;
    loseGame.setFont(font);
    loseGame.setCharacterSize(40);
    loseGame.setPosition(80.f, 150.f);
    loseGame.setColor(sf::Color::White);
    loseGame.setString("You lost, press 'Space' to play again.");

    // Load the sounds used in the game
    sf::SoundBuffer ballSoundBuffer;
    if (!ballSoundBuffer.loadFromFile("loseSound.wav"))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    sf::Sound loseGameSound(ballSoundBuffer);


    while (true)
    {
        window.clear(Color::Color(49, 79, 79));

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::Space))
            goto restart;
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::Escape)) 
            break;

        ball.update();
        paddle.update();
        collisionTest(paddle, ball);
        for (auto& brick : bricks) collisionTest(brick, ball);
        bricks.erase(remove_if(begin(bricks), end(bricks),
            [](const Brick& mBrick)
        {   
            return mBrick.destroyed;
        }),
            end(bricks));

        if (isPlaying)
        {
            window.draw(ball.shape);
            window.draw(paddle.shape);
            for (auto& brick : bricks) window.draw(brick.shape);
        }

        else
        {
            window.clear(Color::Black);
            // Draw the pause message
            loseGameSound.play();
            window.draw(loseGame);
            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::Space))
                goto restart;

        }

        window.display();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have SFML installed right now, so I didn't test you code, but here are some suggestions on improvements you can look into:

#### Avoid `using namespace` at the global level

This is a common issue with single-file programs. When projects are small, this is not very harmful, but can break builds in larger code bases due to name collisions. A namespace is a way of allowing identical names to coexist peacefully, if you use namespace at the global scope, that advantage is lost. Namespace names are usually sort precisely to make it easy qualifying the references with the namespace prefix. `sf::` and `std::` are not an annoyance to type.

#### One declaration per line

Longer lines with multiple declarations are less clear. In a long line like the following, it takes a few extra milliseconds to realize how many constants are 
being declared:

> ```
> constexpr float paddleWidth( 100.f ), paddleHeight( 20.f ), paddleVelocity( 8.f );
> ```

Put each declaration in its own line. `paddleVelocity` is not even related to the sizes, so one less reason for that not be coupled in the same line.

Also, you're generally consistent by initializing all variables with the `{ }` syntax, but those constants at the top are using parentheses.

#### Don't use mutable global data

It might be tempting to declare a few global variables when the code is small, but at scale, they are a sure recipe for bugs. Use function parameters to pass data around as much as you can. It will make dependencies explicit and easy to track down. `isPlaying` is actually only used inside `main`, so it doesn't even make sense for it to be a global.

The global integer `x` also seems unused. But worse, `main` apparently redeclares it, so that's probably an artifact from a previous version of the code. Always compile your code with the highest warning levels available. They will remind you of this kind of mistakes, like unused variables and names shadowed by legal but conflicting declarations.

#### Implement proper inheritance

The class `Rectangle` serves as base for two other classes. You could actually implement both `Paddle` and `Brick` by using composition instead, e.g. just by making them *have* a `Rectangle` member instead of *being rectangles*, this tends to make things simpler in the long run.

Nevertheless, when you do use inheritance, you have to decide how the base class destructor is going to be declared. There are two options:

1. If child classes can be `delete`d from a base class pointer (e.g. delete a `Rectangle` instance that is in fact a `Brick`), then the base class must have a **public `virtual` destructor**.
2. If you'd like to disallow deleting an instance from a base class pointer, or you don't need this feature, them you can make the base destructor **protected and non-virtual**.

**Side note:** You're actually using `struct` for your object types. As far as the language is concerned, there's no distinction between structs and classes, besides the default access level. However, the usual convention is to use `class` for polymorphic types or types with some behavior/logic and leave `struct` for [Plain-Old-Data (POD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) types.

#### Use `const` methods

Your helpers and accessors in `Rectangle` and `Ball` are not modifying member variables, so they should be `const` methods, to both allow them being called on a const instance of the classes and also to clearly convey that info to the readers of your code. More about it [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns).

Related are functions that take read-only parameters by reference, like `isIntersecting`. This method should not change the objects passed in, so it should take them by const reference:

```
bool isIntersecting(const T1& mA, const T2& mB) {
                    ^^^^^         ^^^^^
```

#### Please avoid `goto`

The fact that you are resorting to `goto` is a clear sign that `main` is overly complicated and needs immediate refactoring. Rethink it by breaking the distinct logic sections into separate functions and get rid of those `goto`s by using structured loops.

#### Default `{ }` can help readability

The lack of `{ }` in these nested loops added to that line broken at the start of the function gives the wrong idea, from a quick glance, about the structure of this piece of code. My suggestion is to add default curly braces when you have more complex statements like nested loops, even if the inner statement is a one-liner

> ```
>  for (int iX{ 0 }; iX < countBlocksX; ++iX)
>      for (int iY{ 0 }; iY < countBlocksY; ++iY)
>          bricks.emplace_back(
>              (iX + 1) * (blockWidth + 3) + 22, (iY + 2) * (blockHeight + 3));
> ```

Suggested:

```
for (int iX{ 0 }; iX < countBlocksX; ++iX)
{
    for (int iY{ 0 }; iY < countBlocksY; ++iY)
    {
        bricks.emplace_back(
            (iX + 1) * (blockWidth  + 3) + 22, 
            (iY + 2) * (blockHeight + 3));
    }
}
```